# Removing shadows

Tags: light, shadows

How do I remove an object's shadow ? I do not have a node setup for either object as I would not know where to start with tackling this issue. Also, the small object will be animated to move, hence its a moving shadow issue and not static one. Thanks in advance.
d[image: Shadow]

Comment: Cycles or EEVEE?

Comment: In Cycles, select your object, go in the Properties panel > Object > Visibility > Ray Visibility > Shadow

Comment: I don't see the "Ray Visibility" option in Blender 2.8. But there is a 'Shadow' selection. But there is a 'Shadow' box in the 'Viewport Display' of the Visibility section. Unfortunately when I UNtick that box to remove shadow, the shadow still remains.... both in Cycles and EEVEE mode.

Comment: excuse my grammar before.... "But there is a 'Shadow' box in the 'Viewport Display' ........   "

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting to disable shadows per material.

[image]

But it seems to have more disadvantages compared to Cycles. But it should work in your case.

[image]

You can also use compositor to remove shadows and more.

[image]

The key things here:

1. Object render visibility is an object setting.
2. Collection visibility is a view layer setting.
3. Transparent is a scene setting

[image]

4. Two scenes in one file are simply two blend files being in one, which can have links between.

Here is the file where I also wanted to achieve saving the background for one of the two shots. If you do not need it you can skip the scene part and use only view layers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It does have a setting to disable it: [make-an-object-not-cast-a-shadow-in-eevee](/questions/139822/make-an-object-not-cast-a-shadow-in-eevee/139830#139830)

Comment: @Hikariztw Thanks, I did not think of it in even though I did check that menu to change alpha setting. I should have been paying more attention. Seems this is some tricky method. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Hikariztw Funny enough, looking at your comment "Cycles or EEVEE?", I assured myself that EEVEE does not have it, because in the opposite case, you could have written an answer for both. I have distinguished the renderers by slightly different interfaces for object properties.

Comment: thanks for replying. I'm using Blender 2.8 and I don't see those nodes - 'Render Layers', Composite and 'Alpha over' listed in the node selection list.

Comment: @Steb Those nodes are compositor nodes not shader.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Blender professional and I am still a beginner as I use it to render some sketches in order to plan paintings. Don't know if I can help you but I guess that you are trying to recreate the motion of the moon around the Earth. In this sense, the render is cute accurate, the light (sun) in your scene is behind the moon, you have a sun eclipse there.

-You could put a medium but large light on the opposite part of the planet so it can ligth the moon but keep the earth visible as well. this is more realistic because the dark part of the moon is not visible from Earth, in your scene the dark part of the moon faces the Earth

-You can run the moon as a low emission object, it wont generate a shadow and might solve the problem if you only want to describe movement, you migth want to use a curve form as ligth if you some sahdow is still showing.

Comment: as an emission object I refer that you just have to adjust the Transmission properties on the nodes.

Comment: Placing the sun on the other side works, I just tried. If you change  the angle properties on the ligth-sun menu on the rigth panel, you will see the Earth with equal ligth on its whole surface. Or you can change the Earth material so you can visualize where is nigth or where is daytime

Comment: When I thought why does he need it, I was thinking of motion design like when you compare planet sizes because turning off Moon's or an asteroid's shadow is weird. 

Comment: I appreciate the input guys but the small object is not meant to be the Moon. I simply want the shadow removed completely. Cheers.